# Cannot find module '@ionic-native/text-to-speech/ngx' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native, ionic5

I have the latest version of Ionic installed. I've been trying this for a very long time, but no method I tried is working for me.

I am following the Ionic documentation, but I'm still facing this error.

This is my .ts file and I am getting error on line 2.

alphabet.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TextToSpeech } from '@ionic-native/text-to-speech/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-alphabet',
  templateUrl: './alphabet.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alphabet.page.scss'],
})
export class AlphabetPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private tts: TextToSpeech) { 
    this.tts.speak('Hello World')
  .then(() => console.log('Success'))
  .catch((reason: any) => console.log(reason));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "KidsFun",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.3.1",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.3",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.1.3",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.6",
    "@ionic-native/text-to-speech": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-tts": "^0.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.3.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you do "npm install @ionic-native/text-to-speech"?

Comment: @faisalMehboob I referred these simple steps from ionic documentation, check this out 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/text-to-speech

Comment: Can you add your package.json and tsconfig.json to your question?

Comment: yes this is my package.json - [link](https://ufile.io/lqpypvt7)
and this is my tsconfig.json - [link](https://ufile.io/fkz5mgvj)

Comment: Can you copy paste the content to your question?

Comment: I have edited the question and copy-pasted my package.json and tsconfig.json above.
please let me know.

Comment: Can you also copy content of your 'tsconfig.app.json' file?

Comment: Yes i have updated please let me know

Comment: @faisalMehboob is there any solution for this?

Comment: Can you try changing baseURL to src like "baseUrl": "src" on your tsconfig.json file?

Comment: @FaisalMehboob, baseUrl cannot be replaced with src. It says unknown property src

Comment: @AatifaKhan I am also seeing same problem, did you get any resolution on this.